# Visual C++ 2012 and PCRE

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio, visual-c++, pcre

I'm new to C++ but I need to use PCRE library in my project. I've already downloaded PCRE 8.20 for windows from [this page](http://www.airesoft.co.uk/pcre). Now how can I tell Visual Studio where the library is so that `#include <pcre.h>` would work?

I know that C++ already has `<regex>` library but ECMAScript regular expressions are too limiting for me (no possessive quantifiers for example).

Comment: In the directory of your project?

Comment: No, elsewhere. Since it's external library one copy for all projects should be enough right? I just need to add some paths to .lib/.dll/.h files, isn't that right? Or should I copy some of them into my project?

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the pcre include path in the additional include folders list (idem for library path)? 
If not see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for additional include folders and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe.aspx) for additional library folders

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Or at least partially. To use the pcrecpp::RE class I [probably need](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/pcre/pcrecpp.html) to include pcrecpp.h file as well but it's not in the inc folder, only in src folder. I tried to include it anyway but it want's to also include pcrecpparg.h file which I can't find anywhere. I'm probably not supposed to include pcrecpp.h from src folder, so what else can I do to get the pcrecpp::RE class?

Comment: This build (pcre for windows) is pretty messed up.I fear that you'll have to include the pcre/src folder as well to be able to use the c++ wrapper.You have a pcrecpparg.h.in that you can rename to pcrecpparg.h in the src folder. .h.in file generally generates .h during configure/build but that's not the case for this release.Consider building your own copy in the future as  this build does not seem very serious

Comment: I also hope that the cpp wrapper was compiled in the library ... If not (if you get unresolved dependencies) you may need to also add pcrecpp.h/.cpp to your project.

Comment: Well that's the problem - it was not. Renaming .h.in to .h just leads to another error. I fixed them and then yet different error and so on. The solution is probably compiling pcrecpp.lib but that's way outside of my league. :-(

Comment: post the errors you get after including the pcrecp.h and pcrecpp.cpp to your solution.we'll try to help.Step by step :)

Comment: Here we go, i happen to have a vm with a vs2008.I compiled pcre for you : http://www.filedropper.com/pcremsvc8  .All config options are left to the default (except unicode support). It's a 32 bit build and you'll find a lib and a (complete) include folder. you'll have to link against pcre and pcrecpp.Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I greatly appriciate your effort, unfortunately the download link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Stupid file hosting, I put here too https://hotfile.com/dl/200656355/e0c421b/PCRE_msvc8.zip.html .

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it but I got this error when including pcrecpp.h (I use Visual C++ Express 2012): warning C4251: 'pcrecpp::RE::pattern_' : class 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'pcrecpp::RE' C:\PCRE\inc\pcrecpp.h 701

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the zip file. Copy all the content into your solution explorer, and then when adding `pcre.h` add it as `inc/pcre.h` That should work.